# c++ inheritance overload member

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I have two classes A, B where B inherits A. I have two structs C, D, where D inherits C. A instantiates a number of structs C as members. How can I achieve that B instantiates members of struct D instead of C?
I could of course add D as a new member to B but then B would also allocate memory for C, which would be wastefull.

Comment: Could you show some code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates?

```
template <typename ContainedT = C>
class A {
    ContainedT x, y, z;
};

class B : public A<D> {
    ...
};
```